# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Genre'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is the error I ran into and I am not sure what is causing this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/anishchowdary/Couch to Coder/Week 4/using_pandas.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(number_of_books_written.Genre)
  File "/Users/anishchowdary/PycharmProjects/ISAconverter/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 6202, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Genre'
```

This is the code that I used:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bestsellers = pd.read_csv("bestsellers with categories.csv")
sellers = bestsellers.drop_duplicates(subset='Name', keep='last')

number_of_books_written = sellers.groupby('Genre')[['Name']].count().sort_values("Name", ascending=False).head(10)

print(number_of_books_written.Genre)
```

Comment: `Genre` is not a column but the index, you can use `as_index=False` in `groupby`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with `print(number_of_books_written.Genre)` part.

`groupby` method does not keep the grouping columns as columns, it becomes an index.

You can try calling genres via `index`:

```py
print(number_of_books_written.index)
```

Comment: your `Genre` column became the new dataframes' `index`, because you used it as a group. Try `.groupby(['Genre', 'Name'])` as an example -- it'll group by 2 columns, and **both** of them become index (multi-index df)